Remap a mess from a 2D Mesh to 3D mesh
I have 2D mesh (source) and 3D mesh (target), they both have same UV layout and topology. I have another mesh (called A) laid on the 2D Mesh. see the pic below
What I want to do is to transfer Mesh A from 2D mesh to 3D mesh. Anybody has ideas how to do it manually in blender? or any other ideas?

Thank you so much

hi @moonboots, what i mean by transfer is to create a copied Torus on the 3D mesh. Please advise if you have the ideas
